# change URL of PHP get request when sending form data to script

Tags: php, .htaccess

Right now, upon form submission, the URL looks like:

(where 'query' is the submitted data)

```
http://mySite.com/index.php?search=query
```

or

```
http://mySite.com/?search=query
```

How can I make it

```
http://mySite.com/search?q=query
```

If possible to do it without editing the .htaccess file, then please tell me how.

Or if it is necessary to edit .htaccess, please teach me what rule to add so that all queries have a URL in that form when submitted.

Comment: why you need to use search?? remove that and use url as `http://mySite.com/?q=query`..

Comment: you have to rewrite rules in .htaccess file

Comment: @saveATcode I want to make it clear that, in this case, the submission was a search.

Comment: @messifan what is the rule I need to add to get that

Comment: @IrfanMir: search?? what i see is search is the name of parameter in which you are passing "query" as data..am i wrong??

Comment: No, you are not wrong. Query is the data and search is the name of the HTML input field data is typed in.

Comment: OR you can redirect to `/search?q=query` from index.php file... i would do that rather than use of rewrite rules in this case. [rewrite rules also has cost], and they will be checked on every page load

Comment: The only thing i know is that you will use htaccess on this. Create a rewrite rules.

Comment: Actually, i have one more question. **Why** is the original url `/index?search=query` ? i mean, if this is form submission, you can set form target to `/search` in first place. So whats the reason?

Comment: @poncha how do you We it to /search ? Right now, it is `myDomain.com/?search=query with search the name of field and query being the data submitted.

Comment: @IrfanMir `<form action="/search" method="get"><input type="text" name="q"> ...` that is of course if search comes via form submission

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend redirecting from *index.php* rather than use of rewrite rules in this case.
Rewrite rules also have cost, and they will be checked on every page load

In the beginning of *index.php*:

```
<?php
if(!empty($_GET["search"]))
{
    header("Location: search?q=".rawurlencode($_GET["search"]));
    exit;
}
?>
```

As **Olaf Dietsche** rightfully noted in the comments, mod_rewrite outperforms PHP, so the question is really what is the *hit ratio* of index.php vs other files. If it is low, php approach is definitely better, however, if index.php hits 50% of the time or so, then you might be better off with rewriting.

Hence, adding mod_rewrite solution as well:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)search=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^index.php$ /search?q=%1 [R,L]
```

`RewriteCond` actually looks for `search=` query string parameter and ensures it's not empty
And the rule simply rewrites anything from index.php into `/search?q=<query>`
Note that `%1` used to match the first captured sub-pattern matched from the conditions (rather than from the matching part of the rule itself - in which case we would need to use `$1`).

---

However, the real question is why we are dealing with this problem in first place.
If search is done by submitting a value in a page, then it's form submission and as such it can be pointed directly to the handler and not redirected there afterwards. This is much more efficient.

```
<form action="/search" method="get">
<input type="text" name="q">
...
```

This way, anything submitted from the search form will go directly to `/search` and will not need a redirect to deal with.

Comment: Why use !empty(). Should you use is set()? That way when the form is submitted?

Comment: When everything is tunneled through `index.php`, as is almost always the case with PHP frameworks, using PHP for redirecting is even more expensive than `mod_rewrite`.

Comment: @IrfanMir if the form is submitted without a value, then this parameter is still passed, but empty. why search for empty value?

Comment: @OlafDietsche First - not everything, second - `if(!empty())` is far lighter load , and it happens only in index.php, in comparison to regex matching that will have to be done on every page by mod_rewrite ...

Comment: @poncha A simple performance test with `ab` on `localhost` shows otherwise. 10000 requests with PHP `header`: ~8.7 sec, 10000 requests with mod_rewrite: ~5.8 sec. That's +50% for using PHP. So, it all depends on the ratio of `index.php` vs other files.

Comment: @OlafDietsche Well, my server doesn't support .htacess right now. But, I may be switching to one that does.

Comment: @poncha ah, true. I forgot about submitting an empty form.

Comment: @OlafDietsche what do you mean by ratio of index.php to other pages? Right now, index basically introduces the site and links to the other .php pages.

Comment: @IrfanMir How many requests are for `index.php` and how many requests are for other pages. If you have many requests for other pages, then the mod_rewrite solution is bad for performance, because it costs more. If you have many requests for `index.php?search=query`, then the mod_rewrite solution is better, because it is expensive to start and parse PHP for just a redirect.

Comment: @OlafDietsche About 30% of the requests will go `index.php?search=query` and 70% to the other pages. So, the PHP solution is the one I should go to use then, correct?

Comment: @IrfanMir This looks like a coin toss. But with a ratio 30/70, you should be fine with poncha's solution. Depending on the amount of traffic you have, this might be a non-issue anyway. So unless you have lots of requests, you should choose the solution, you're most comfortable with.

Answer (score 1):

To add a mod_rewrite solution. You must check for `index.php` and a `search=` query string

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} search=(.*)
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /search?q=%1 [R,L]
```